# Why can't I start two threads inside constructor __init__() of a python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, class

I'm simply trying to run two different daemon threads and print a line from each for testing. While this code works :

```
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
from myFunctions import *


class Monitoring:

    def alarms(self):
        return alarms.run()

    def generator(self):
        return generator.run()

    def run(self):
        generator = threading.Thread(target=self.alarms)
        generator.daemon = True
        generator.start()

        alarm = threading.Thread(target=self.generator)
        alarm.daemon = True
        alarm.start()

        print("started thread")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        d = Monitoring()
        d.daemon = True
        d.run()

        print("started the thread")

        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        alarms.close()
        generator.close()
        print("Main - Keyboard interrupt in __main__")
```

Something like this doesn't seem to work and only the first thread "alarms" start. Why is that?

```
class Monitoring:

    def __init__(self,a,g):
        self.a = a
        self.g = g


    def run(self):
        generator = threading.Thread(target=self.a)
        generator.daemon = True
        generator.start()

        alarm = threading.Thread(target=self.g)
        alarm.daemon = True
        alarm.start()

        print("@class run() ")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        d = Monitoring(alarms.run(), generator.run())
        d.daemon = True
        d.run()

        print("@__main__")

        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        alarms.close()
        generator.close()
        print("Main - Keyboard interrupt in __main__")
```

Comment: In `d = Monitoring(alarms.run(), generator.run())` the function `alarms.run` (and `generator.run`) is called instantly instead of in a new thread. Probably you want `d = Monitoring(alarms.run, generator.run)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot MIchael, coming from Javascript I couldn't get this working. Feel free to add the reply and I'll accept it. it wokred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
d = Monitoring(alarms.run(), generator.run())
```

the functions `alarms.run` and `generator.run` are called instantly and the return values (probably `None`) are given as arguments to the `Monitoring` constructor.

To use the function objects as arguments (which are then called in a new thread), use

```
d = Monitoring(alarms.run, generator.run)
```

instead.